# Is there a better way to assign an Eloquent relationship in Laravel using a Repository?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Assuming I have these 2 Models `User` and `Account`.

Where a `User` can have multiple `Accounts`. (hasMany)

And an `Account` belongs to a `User`. (belongsTo)

If I'm **not** using a Repository I would save the model and its relationship like this:

```
    $account = new Account();
    $account->username = $this->username;
    $account->secret = $this->secret;
    $account->user()->associate($this->user);
    $account->save();
```

And when using a Repository I see many people (and articles) doing it like this:

```
$accountRepository->create([
      'username' => $this->username,
      'secret'   => $this->secret,
      'user_id'  => $this->user()->id,
]);
```

My problem with this approach is in the `user_id` because it doesn't feel safe to manually assign this kind of relationship, additionally when someone else is reading this code he cannot tell what is the relation between the `Account` and `User` from there!!

The way I'm currently handling this is as follow: *(it's kinda combination of the both ways)*

```
    // create the account and attach the fields and the relationships
    $account = new Account();
    $account->username = $this->username;
    $account->secret = $this->secret;
    $account->user()->associate($this->user);

    // save the new created model with the repository
    $account = $accountRepository->create($account->toArray());
```

But I'm not really sure if there's any better way to do this!!
All I need is to use the `associate` function because it feels safer and looks better for the readers. And to use a Repository to save and access my data.

Note: I am using the https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository to abstract the database layer.

Comment: gee I wish someone had answered you, I'm wondering the same thing right now.

Comment: Me too! But maybe you can you use attach from models or sync from the repository?

Comment: Why couldn't you just create a method inside your account repository called for example createWithUserAssociation()? Then you would be able to pass your account data and user object to it.

Answer (score 0):

You're designing your own repository, so you can make your functionality as explicit as you'd like. Instead of passing in the related fields or objects in the data array, add the extra dependencies as extra parameters.

```
class AccountRepository
{
    public function create($attributes, $user = null) {
        $account = new Account($attributes);
        
        if (!empty($user)) {
            $account->user()->associate($user);
        }
        
        $account->save();

        return $account;
    }
}
```

Now, you'd call your function like this:

```
$accountRepository->create([
    'username' => $this->username,
    'secret'   => $this->secret,
], $this->user());
```

Now your calling code only knows the dependencies of the function it is calling. It doesn't need to know the details of how they're related, or the keys that have to be set to relate them. It just knows that it the function needs a `User` if the account needs one.

Answer (score -2):

```
$accountRepository->create([
    'username' => $this->username,
    'secret' => $this->secret,
    'user_id' => $this->user->id,
]);


// AccountRepository.php
public function createWithUser($data, User $user)
{
    $account = new Account($data);
    $account->user()->associate($user);
    $account->save();
    return $account;
}

// Usage in your code
$account = $accountRepository->createWithUser([
    'username' => $this->username,
    'secret' => $this->secret,
], $this->user);
```

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @DavidW I'm not flagging due to the strike, but we do have delete vote privileges

Comment: @miken32 my current view is that downvotes (and comments pointing it out to attract downvotes) may be the best option since I don't think it takes that much for the system to start imposing fairly long timeouts. But delete votes are good too.

Comment: @DavidW I think it's the only way we'll get rid of this stuff since the mods' hands have been tied. Downvotes are a tool of limited use, since the serial voting script kicks in past 2 daily votes on a user.

Comment: You should add explanation.